# Problem with kde-filesystem when updating

Tags: fedora, yum, update, kde

Since 2-3 weeks, each time I update my fedora 11 box with yum, I get these messages.

> Error unpacking rpm package kde-filesystem-4-33.fc11.noarch
>   warning: /etc/rpm/macros.kde4 saved as /etc/rpm/macros.kde4.rpmsave
>   error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/share/doc/HTML/fr/docs/common: cpio: rename
>
> Failed:
>   kde-filesystem.noarch 0:4-33.fc11

Everything else works fine.

I tried to reinstall it. The re-installation was fine but I still get the messages when I

```
yum update
```

I didn't try to remove it with yum because it will remove more than 100 packages dues to dependencies.

What else could I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed the directory common

```
mv /usr/share/doc/HTML/fr/docs/common /usr/share/doc/HTML/fr/docs/common_old
```

and it works!

Thanks to me :-)